# Write IEnumerator for Movement

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to write an IEnumerator to move at the desire distance at a specified time. I have tried to write the code for this but this is running a different way.

```
     float moveDistance=1f;
     float moveSpeed=5f;
     float elapsedDistance = 0f;

     while (elapsedDistance <= moveDistance)
     {
         elapsedDistance += Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

         Vector3 cubeLocalPosition = transform.localPosition;
         cubeLocalPosition.y += Time.deltaTime * moveDistance;
         transform.localPosition = cubeLocalPosition;
         yield return null;
     }
```

Through this code, Object can't able to travel 1 unit distance. How can I correct this code?

Comment: Does this object have a rigidbody attached? What kind of behavior are you experiencing? Is it moving at all?

Answer (score 0):

Following your own rotation, you calculate the finalpoint to go
and after,
you could use [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) or [Vector.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) to move in the specified time..So the moving speed adapt itself following the time desired

```
var endpoint = transform.position + transform.forward.normalized * distance;
StartCoroutine(MoveToPosition(transform, endpoint, 3f)
:
:
public IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Transform transform, Vector3 positionToGO, float timeToMove)
{
  var currentPos = transform.position;
  var t = 0f;
  while (t < 1f)
  {
    t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, positionToGO, t);
    yield return null;
  }
  transform.position = positionToGO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop condition uses elapsedDistance which is increasing with moveSpeed. That latter is 5 so it will be 1 in 1/5 of a second. Your object is likely only moving 0.2unit.

you should use Mathf.Lerp or MoveTowards

```
float distance = 1f;
float time = 0f;
float period = 1f; // how long in second to do the whole movement
yield return new WaitUntil(()=>
{
    time += Time.deltaTime / period;
    float movement = Mathf.Lerp(0f, distance, time);
    Vector3 cubeLocalPosition = transform.localPosition;
    cubeLocalPosition.y += movement;
    transform.localPosition = cubeLocalPosition;
    return time >= 1f;
});
```